# Rendering Overwriting Transparency When Rendering to Texture When Using Transparency

Tags: java, opengl

When rendering to a texture (secondary framebuffer) in **OpenGL**, anything transparent overwrites the transparency of what is below, rather than adding transparency as transparency should. This means if I render a transparent object on top of an existing opaque object, the result is a texture that is transparent, even though it should be opaque.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0YiT.png]

In this picture, the space is rendered as a background normally, the `framebuffer` is then changed and opaque blue is then rendered, then, the green/red are rendered. The texture that the `framebuffer` was rendering to is used to render onto the original `framebuffer`(the window), and the result is as seen.

Some code:

Framebuffer/Texture Creation:

```
        int texture = glGenTextures();
        framebufferID = glGenFramebuffers();
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,framebufferID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        int width,height;
        width = (int)(getMaster().getWindow().getWidth()*(xscale/(16f*getMaster().getGuiCamera().getWidth()))*1.2f);
        height = (int)(getMaster().getWindow().getHeight()*(yscale/9f)*1.15f);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture,0);
        int depth = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depth, 0);
        this.texture = new Texture(texture,width,height,true);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);
```

The depth buffer here was something I tried to get it to work, but it had no effect on the output texture though.

Render Code:

```
        getMaster().returnToViewportAfterFunction(new Vector2i(texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight()),
            () -> getMaster().returnToFramebufferAfterFunction(framebufferID, () -> {

                shapeShader.bind();
                glEnable(GL_BLEND);
                glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                model.bind();
                shapeShader.setUniform("color", 0f, 0f, 1f, 1f); //Blue
                shapeShader.setUniform("projection", this.camera.getProjectionForGuiWindow(vec2zero, xscale, yscale));
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVerticeCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

                shapeShader.setUniform("color", 0f, 1f, 0f, 0.5f); //Green
                shapeShader.setUniform("projection", this.camera.getProjectionForGuiWindow(vec2zero, xscale/2f, yscale/2f));
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVerticeCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

                shapeShader.setUniform("color", 1f, 0f, 0f, .2f); //Red
                shapeShader.setUniform("projection", this.camera.getProjectionForGuiWindow(vec2zero, xscale/4f, yscale/2f));
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVerticeCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

                glDisable(GL_BLEND);

                model.unbind();
            })
        );
        //Renders the texture we just made
        shader.bind();
        model.bind();
        textureCoords.bind(texture);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        shader.setUniform("color", 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        shader.setUniform("projection", camera.getProjectionForGuiWindow(getPosition(), xscale, yscale));
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVerticeCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);

        model.unbind();
```

Rendering over opaque objects in `framebuffer` 0 with a transparent object does not cause the resulting pixels to be transparent, else they would appear as a blend of the `glClearColor` and the opaque object, so why does this happen in the `framebuffer` in which I am using to render to a texture? Shouldn't it be consistent? I feel that maybe I'm missing some attachment to my `framebuffer` but I can't be sure what. I saw a solution that said to use `glColorMask(true,true,true,false)`, the last false meaning no alpha writes, which appears at first glance to work, but why should I disable transparency when transparency is what I'm going for? It also appears to cause many issues if left on. Can anyone lend some insight? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the glColorMask was not the solution, after further analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a *separable blending function* which treats RGB and Alpha values separately: [glBlendFuncSeparate](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFuncSeparate.xhtml). For the RGB values you keep using `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ONE_MINUS_ALPHA`. For the Alpha values use something like `GL_ONE, GL_ONE` so that things simply add up.

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

Comment: Wow, this appears to work! My biggest question is why? What stumps me is that transparency using glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) works for transparency in the normal framebuffer (fbo #0), so why doesn't it work in a framebuffer linked to a texture? Is there something I need to edit on the framebuffer to make the simpler function work, or is there something fundamental I am misunderstanding? I checked just now and can confirm that both functions look the same in fbo 0 but both functions do not look the same in any other fbo. Forgive me for asking, but I need to understand.

Comment: @PoisonedPorkchop: The reason is, that unless a `GL_DST_…` blend func is specified the destination alpha value simply isn't taken into account during blending, hence if the destination alpha is going "bonkers" the effects are not seen. That does change however if the resulting destination alpha values are used as input into a later rendering pass as source alpha values. This is what happens in your case: You're rendering something to a texture and the blend func you have, will just pass on the transparent alpha to the destination pixels, overwriting the opaque, if you don't use separation.

Comment: So, something like this?
    glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA);

Comment: The above code fixes the issue of overwriting existing alpha values, but it doesn't appear to stack alpha values (aka two half transparency objects rendered on top of each other results in a half transparency object, while an opaque object and a half transparency object results in an opaque object).

Comment: @PoisonedPorkchop: With the values you suggested, the source alpha gets multiplied with itself and the destination alpha, too, is multiplied with itself, before getting summed together. I.e. you get `s² + d²`.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the algorithm worked like that, thought it did some magic numbers behind the scenes depending on what you gave it. Is there a combo that gives more correct opacity combination? With glone and glone, if I'm not mistaken, this means .5 rendered on top of already .5 opacity would equal 1 opacity, while in real life I think the effect of the opacity would be multiplicative. What I mean is that 0.5 opacity means half of whatever is behind should be visible and half of what is on top should be visible. If you put .5 on top of .5 then that should be .25 opacity, or alpha = 0.75

Comment: Any way to get the numbers above?

Comment: Also, when I said opacity above I meant transparency, termwise @datenwolf

Comment: What about glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA,GL_ONE)?

Comment: Works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, best solution to my issue was to use glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA,GL_ONE) instead of glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)